# How to find the latest com port created in my pc?

Tags: windows, winapi, usb, device-driver

How to find the latest virtual COM port created in my Pc??

device manager -> ports -> devicename ( **COM X** ).

How to find that "COM x" programatically?

Comment: "Latest" gives no guarantee whatsoever that you actually want to *use* that port.  Generate a list with WMI, Win32_SerialPort class and let the user pick the right one.  And yes, that's why virtual COM ports suck pretty bad.

Comment: sorry can i detect the last COMX created???

Comment: Yes you can "find" them programatically, but find based on what? You can't rely on any particular ordering. If it's a custom device, you can filter based on the vendor and device ID, or maybe a custom name.

Comment: ya i have a specific vendor id and device id. But how can i achieve with these credentials programatically.. am a newbie.. could u please explain in detail>>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the [SetupApi](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff550897%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), specifically the [`SetupDiEnumDeviceInfo()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff551010%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [`CM_Get_Device_ID()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff538405%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) functions.

[This project](http://code.google.com/p/usb-devices-list/source/browse/trunk/usb-device-list/USBDeviceList/CUSBDevices.cs) has some sample code that shows the usage.

Answer (score 0):

"Install Date" is one of the properties on the details tab of a hardware properties page from device manager.

I expected to be able to find a key in the registry for it:

```
HKLM\SSYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\...
```

But there isn't a key, or at least, I can't find one.

Will a search by VendorID + DeviceID/ProductID be sufficient?

Comment: i want to give the particular comX as input while creating LAN connection.. so can i find the particular COMx programatically??